# How to change the FlowID in Flow Table Screen in axapta?

Tags: axapta, x++

Is it possible to change the FlowID and Structure ID in Galaxy Flow Table in Microsoft Dynamics AX 2009? e.g : If "FLOW ID" is "Import InventTable Items" then I need to change to "Import IN_Items" and If "STRUCTURE ID" is "Import Items" then I need to change to "Import_Items".

Comment: Yes.In 'Galaxy' Flow Table screen only.

Comment: This is not programming related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FlowId may be renamed. Right click the record, choose "Record information". From the "Record information" click the "Rename" button.

Same thing with structure id, rename from the structure form.